# How to run a python script on flask backend?

Tags: python, flask

I have a small flask app where it takes user input and returns some text. Here the user input is fed to another python script say temp.py and this temp.py will return a value which should be returned to user. For eg:

## flask.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def result():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/getconfig', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def config():
    value = request.form['config']
    print ("This is the user value :  ", value);
    // This value is written to a file say x.pol and my temp.py reads from x.pol file and writes the output to y.pol. I'm not sure how to trigger the script like "python temp.py" on the server.
    // The reason I'm doing this because I don't want to tweak the third party tool where, the third party tool reads from input files and generates output files. 

    return content_generated_by_temp.py // by reading y.pol.

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

By the way, temp.py is itself a nightmare. I understood what the tool does. For more info about the tool: [Google Caprica](https://github.com/google/capirca)

Comment: Use `os` module to call this other python script in `temp.py` or better way would be to make a function in `temp.py`, import that function and call from flask app.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I cannot make it as function. I added the tool I'm using. It has so many dependencies and I don't want to touch any of them as it may ruin the generated pols.

Comment: then, `os` module can do your job. After that, read the output file generated by temp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap whatever `temp.py` is doing in a function. Place it in the same directory as `flask.py`. Call `import temp` in `flask.py`, then use `temp.myfunction()`

Comment: I'd suggest this over ```os``` for sure.  Not that ```os``` is wrong, but this feels a lot better.  **And** you _should_ be make able to make it return an object rather than writing to disk and having to read it back in.